# how to draw graph of records in WPF by using graphviz4net

Tags: .net, wpf, graph, graphviz

From http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf, I see an example of drawing of records. I am wondering how to achieve that in wpf.

[image]

Comment: Aware of family tree project ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan what we need is fully supported graph (both directed and un-directed). Composition of records in a single node is one of those requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported in .NET wrapper.